# Refactor Nested For Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, nested-loops

**Instructions**

Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

**Example**

```
Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9, return [0, 1].
```

How can I refactor this to eliminate the nested for-loop? I'd like to get the time complexity down.

**Code**

```js
const twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    for(let i in nums){
      for(let j in nums) {
        if(nums[i] + nums[j] === target && nums[i] != nums[j]) {
            return [i, j];
        }
      }
    }
};

console.log(twoSum([2, 7, 11, 15], 9));
```

Comment: `for...in...` is not meant to be used with arrays

Comment: The array will be always sorted or not?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? The algorithm isn't that complicated.

Comment: _"I'd like to get the time complexity down."_ - It won't get any better than that.

Comment: @Andreas yeah, i was told that too but in this case, the problem is asking to return the indices of the 2 elements that add up to the target. What else can I use instead?

Comment: @Andreas there has to be a way that is quicker than what I have. It's telling me that my solution has a `Runtime: 3708 ms, faster than 5.01% of JavaScript online submissions for Two Sum.`

Comment: @MaheerAli I believe the array will **not** be sorted everytime, so that needs to be taken into account

Comment: There's a difference between "time complexity" and actual runtime duration... - If you're lucky the first two elements match the target. In the worst case the last two or none match the target. But the time complexity is in both cases the same because the algorithm is the same.

Comment: @and1 I think you can't make time complexity better than `O(n ^ 2)` if array is not sorted. If it is you can then make it `O(n)`

Comment: @MaheerAli ah so there's no `filter` method that can be applied or anything that would give a quicker solution than a nested for loop?

Comment: @and1 Whatever way you use there will be a kind of nested loop there.

Comment: @MaheerAli is this because we have to use 2 different ways to compare the each element to each other? Not sure if that made sense

Comment: Use the correct `for` loop and think about the elements you have to check and adjust the variables of the outer and inner loop accordingly.

Comment: @Andreas ah icic, so time complexity and runtime are not exactly the same? they shouldn't be used interchangeably??

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity

Comment: @Andreas so i have heard not to use `for-in` loops for arrays, but if we're looking to return the indices, couldn't it work in this case? or is it bad practice or something to do so

Comment: What is the function even supposed to do?  You just pasted a block of code and a console.log line, but that doesn't explain what it should do.  As asked, a valid solution would be to remove the contents of your function.

Comment: @MattHuggins revised for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the difference of each element with the target inside an object with the result as keys and the index as values. This will make checking for the existence of an element inside an object without looping though the whole content. In a different loop check if the array elements exist in the object, if they do then you have got the pair. The additional condition is to prevent comparing an element with itself.

```js
const twoSum = function(nums, target) {  
  const temp = {};
  for(let i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
    temp[target - nums[i]] = i;
  }

  for(let i=0; i<nums.length-1; i++) {
    if(temp[nums[i]] && temp[nums[i]] !== i) {
      return [i, temp[nums[i]]]
    }
  }
};

console.log(twoSum([2, 11, 7, 17], 9));
console.log(twoSum([1, 3, 4, 2], 6));
```

Comment: `twoSum([2, 11, 15, 7], 9)`

Comment: This only solves the given problem in the given test case but not in every case.

Comment: appreciate the response and it works but when trying a different test case, `[3, 3], 6`, it's giving me `undefined`

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, I think sorting the array solves the issue.

Comment: OP needs the index of the elements. Sorting destroys the order/index.

Comment: Oh yeah, I missed that too

Comment: @Addis this test case does not work, `[1, 3, 4, 2], 6`

Comment: @and1, I have added additional condition to prevent comparing an element with itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem with `O(n)` time. The condition is to solve by this approach is that the array must be sorted.

```js
let twosum = (arr, x) => {
  let s = 0,
    e = arr.length - 1;
  let loc = [];

  while (s < e) {
    if (arr[s] + arr[e] === x) {
      loc.push([s,e]);
      s++;
      e--;
    } else if (arr[s] + arr[e] < x) {
      s++;
    } else {
      e--;
    }
  }

  return loc;
};

console.log(twosum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8], 9));
console.log(twosum([2, 7, 11, 15], 9));
```

The algorithm behind this if anyone interested:

```
1.   Set s value as 0
2.   Set e value as last index say (arr.length - 1)
3.   While s is less than e i.e not pass one another
4.   Check if arr[s] + arr[e] === x then we find it.
4.1. increment s value by 1 as there is no possibility to find any combination before the current s value
4.2. decrement e value by 1 as there is no possibility to find any combination after the current e value
4.3. collect the indexes where the match found.
5.   If arr[s] + arr[e] < x
5.1  increment s as there is no possibility to find any combination before the current s value. But there still has the possibility for the e value to get a match.
6.   If arr[s] + arr[e] > x
6.1  decrement e as there is no possibility to find any combination after the current e value. But there still has the possibility for the s value to get a match.
```

Comment: It returns ```[0, 1]``` for the second solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since this appears to be homework, I'll make a couple suggestions without giving away a complete solution:

- Your current code is repeating index checks.  For example, you're looping over indices [0,1] and [1,0], which will always have the same sum since a+b = b+a.  Instead, I would suggest your loop for `i` go from 0 to len-1, and your loop for `j` go from i+1 to len-1.  That way you will never duplicate checks.
- Part of your current check includes the condition that `nums[i] != nums[j]`, but your problem doesn't state that two values in the array can't be the same.  Is it possible to call this function with values like `toSum([1, 4, 4], 8)` such that 4+4=8?  If so, then you can remove the `nums[i] != nums[j]` check to save time.
- It's not clear if the array provided is sorted.  If it's not, then you could create a tracking variable to account for values you've already checked, and prevent checking them on future iterations.  For example, if you already compared the value 4 against all other values in the array and found no solution, then if you encounter 4 later in the array, there is no reason to check it.

Comment: this is not homework, it's a problem from leetcode that i have attempted and was just curious as to how to refactor without the use of a nested for loop